# List of Lists to HashMap[Index of List] -> List - Scala

Tags: list, scala, hashmap

I have a List of Lists in Scala, that looks likes this: `List(List(1, 5, 6, 10), List(1, 6), List(1, 3, 10)`, I want to convert
    it into a `HashMap[Int, List[Int]]` where the first Int is the index of each list and the `List[Int]` is the list itself. In the end the HashMap should
    look like

```
 HashMap[Int, List[Int]](
      0 -> List(1, 5, 6, 10),
      1 -> List(1, 6),
      2 -> List (1, 3, 10),)
```

Here's my approach, have a list `0` to the length of the list and zip it with this nested list, then somehow
      convert it into a HashMap. But I'm looking for something more idiomatic or neater. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `zipWithIndex` with a `map` should do it:

```
scala> val a = List(List(1, 5, 6, 10), List(1, 6), List(1, 3, 10))
a: List[List[Int]] = List(List(1, 5, 6, 10), List(1, 6), List(1, 3, 10))

scala> a.zipWithIndex.map(_.swap).toMap
res0: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,List[Int]] = 
Map(
    0 -> List(1, 5, 6, 10),
    1 -> List(1, 6), 
    2 -> List(1, 3, 10)
)
```

**Edit:**

If you absolutely need a `HashMap`, things are a little messier:

```
scala> val a = List(List(1, 5, 6, 10), List(1, 6), List(1, 3, 10))
a: List[List[Int]] = List(List(1, 5, 6, 10), List(1, 6), List(1, 3, 10))

scala> val b = a.zipWithIndex.map(_.swap)
b: List[(Int, List[Int])] = List((0,List(1, 5, 6, 10)), (1,List(1, 6)), (2,List(1, 3, 10)))

scala> val hM = collection.immutable.HashMap[Int, List[Int]](b: _*)
hM: scala.collection.immutable.HashMap[Int,List[Int]] = 
Map(
    0 -> List(1, 5, 6, 10),
    1 -> List(1, 6),
    2 -> List(1, 3, 10)
)
```

Comment: use `_.swap` instead of `x => (x._2, x._1)`

Comment: Added, I'll have to remember that!

Comment: Very nice. Is there any way to convert it into a HashMap instead of a Map. My function is complaining expected HashMap[Int, List[Int]], actual: Map[Int, List[Int]].

Comment: @TeodoricoLevoff see my edit for `HashMap` conversion